# How to successfully ignore specs with mocha?

Tags: mocha.js

I use mocha, and I use "skip" and "only" to run specific specs and tests.

But it seems that each time mocha applies these only on the tests.

so if I have this code:

```
var expect = require('expect.js');
var logger = require('log4js').getLogger('TestDemo');

describe('test', function(){
    logger.info('this will appear');
    it('should not appear', function(){
        expect(1+1).to.be(5);
    });
});


describe.only('should run', function(){
    logger.info('this will appear to');
    it('should appear', function(){
        expect(5).to.be(5);
    })
});
```

The output is :

```
[2014-12-12 13:38:37.276] [INFO] TestDemo - this will appear
[2014-12-12 13:38:37.278] [INFO] TestDemo - this will appear to
```

However - the first one is unexpected as I use `describe.only` I don't expect to see prints from any other spec.

Reading their documentation, it should work as I expect it, but it doesn't.

```
 by appending .skip() you may tell Mocha to simply ignore these suite(s) and test-case(s)
```

However it seems mocha does not ignore the suite, only the test-case.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you get has to do with how Mocha discovers your test. Basically Mocha does this:

1. Read all your test files and execute them. The callbacks passed to `describe` are executed *right away*. The callbacks passed to `it` and to the hooks (`before`, `beforeEach`, etc.) are recorded *for later execution*.
2. Mocha executes what it has recorded for later execution (according to some sensible order which is not important here).

What happens when you specify `.only` on your second `describe` is that Mocha does *not* know that you want to execute only this `describe` block *until* it executes it. So when it runs into the first `describe` it has no reason *yet* to skip it. So it executes the callback passed to it.

At the end of the day, though Mocha is executing exactly the tests you told it to execute. (When I run your code here, the Mocha run ends with `1 passing` meaning exactly one test was executed and it passed.) The *test* in the first `describe` is ignored and the test in the second one is executed. If you want to make it so that your calls to `logger.info` will be executed *only* if one or more test in your `describe` block is going to be executed, then put them in `before` hooks:

```
var expect = require('expect.js');
var logger = require('log4js').getLogger('TestDemo');

describe('test', function(){
    before(function () {
        logger.info('this will appear');
    });
    it('should not appear', function(){
        expect(1+1).to.be(5);
    });
});


describe.only('should run', function(){
    before(function () {
        logger.info('this will appear too');
    });
    it('should appear', function(){
        expect(5).to.be(5);
    })
});
```