# Bluebird Each loop in Mocha not working

Tags: javascript, mocha.js, bluebird

I am writing a test where I need to loop over the results of an async api call and dynamically make mocha 'Its' to test each iteration of the response. I found some other related answers which got me started.  Here is what I have tried so far.

```
function getter(uri) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        request({
            method: 'GET',
            json: true,
            uri: uri
        }, function(error, response, body) {
            if (response.statusCode == 200) {
                resolve(body);
            } else {
                reject(error);
            }
        });
    });
}

describe('This works', function() {
    it('works', function(done) {
        getter('myapi_that_returns_an_array').then(function(r) {
            r.should.not.be.empty;
            done();
        }).catch(function(err) {
            done(err);
        });
    });
});


describe('Why not this one', function() {
    getter('myapi_that_returns_an_array').each(function(r) {
        it('should make a test', function(done) {
            r.should.not.be.empty;
            done();
        });
    });
});
```

I tried to just wrap a simple array in a promise and feed that to my test and it works! So I cannot figure out why the api call I make does not work the same way.

```
function simple_test() {
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        resolve([ [1, 2, 3, 4], [2, 3, 4, 1], [3, 4, 2, 1], [4, 1, 2, 3] ]);
        });
}

describe('But this one works', function() {
    two().each(function(r) {
        it('is a test', function(done) {
            r.should.not.be.empty();
            done();
        });
    });
});
```

I tried to add a timeout to simple_test to make it act like the api call - the result is the same as the api call.  Is there a way to do this with Mocha? It looks like the describe is executing before waiting for the promise to resolve.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The version of your test that tries to generate tests by calling `it` inside `getter.each` cannot work because Mocha has no provisions for *generating tests asynchronously* which is what you are trying to do. As I've explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27448769/1906307):

> What you get has to do with how Mocha discovers your test. Basically Mocha does this:
>
> 1. Read all your test files and execute them. The callbacks passed to `describe` are executed *right away*. The callbacks passed to `it` and to the hooks (`before, beforeEach`, etc.) are recorded *for later execution*.
> 2. Mocha executes what it has recorded for later execution (according to some sensible order which is not important here).

The problem with trying to generate tests asynchronously is that by the time the asynchronous code executes you're out of your `describe` block, and the tests are ignored. There is no way to tell Mocha to wait for an asynchronous operation before it considers a `describe` block over.

Comment: bummer - the ability to generate tests asynchronously would be helpful in some situations.  How was you suggest getting around this issue? I guess I could have some sort of check that only uses one assertion.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that you must define the tests synchronously, although each individual test may complete asynchronously.  You can dynamically define `it()` blocks from static data because these tests are defined before the `describe()` call returns.

I don't fully understand why the test works asynchronously with little or no timeout interval, but my experiments suggest that `it()` must be called at least once before `describe()` returns for tests to be recognized in the output.  With a 1 millisecond timeout, I saw tests described in the parent block.

Using `before()` blocks suffers from the same problem.  `before()` could wait for the promised array to resolve, but without any `it()` tests statically defined, `before()` will never get run.

The simple but undesirable alternative would be to have a single `it()` block test all of the data returned by your service.  Another would be to use the results of your web service to first dynamically generate a mocha test file, then run mocha against it.

```
var assert = require("assert");
var Promise = require("bluebird");

var testData = [
    { "name": "Test 1", "value": true },
    { "name": "Test 2", "value": false },
    { "name": "Test 3", "value": true }
];

function getTestData(timeout) {
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        if (timeout) {
            setTimeout(function () {
                resolve(testData);
            }, timeout);
        } else {
            resolve(testData);
        }
    });
}

describe("Dynamicly Generating Tests", function() {

    describe("A: Promised Array, no timeout - Works", function () {
        getTestData().each(function (test) {
            it("A: " + test.name, function () {
                assert.ok(test.value);
            });
        });
    });

    describe("B: Promised Array, short timeout - Works?", function () {
        getTestData(1).then(function (testData) {
            testData.forEach(function (test) {
                it("B:" + test.name, function () {
                    assert.ok(test.value);
                });
            });
        });
    });

    describe("C: Promised Array, timeout, single it() - Works!", function () {
        it("C: Has all correct values", function () {
            return getTestData(1000).each(function (test) {
                assert.ok(test.value, test.name);
            });
        })
    });

});
```

Comment: The "B" series actually does not work. If you comment out the `describe` for "A" and "C" and let it run, you won't get any tests running. The reason is what I explain in my answer. When you have "A" and "C" uncommented, the code in "B" still manages to run but you'll notice that the failure message does not have a complete test name (it lacks the text from the `describe`) because Mocha does not know where the failure originates.