# Mocha/Should.js using asynchronous function

Tags: javascript, node.js, testing, mocha.js, should.js

I'm new to JavaScript test frameworks. I would like to do a little optimization but I run into some problems. The project is using [should.js](http://shouldjs.github.io/)

Here is the simplified version of my original test cases:

```
describe('Simple', function() {
  describe('Test', function() {
    it('should do something', function(done) {
      somePromise.then(function(data) {
        data.should.above(100);
        done();
      });
    }

    it('should do something else but alike', function(done) {
      somePromise.then(function(data) {
        data.should.above(100);
        done();
      });
    }

  }
});
```

I'm trying to do it this way:

```
var testFunc = function(data) {
  it('should do something', function(done) {
      data.should.above(100);
      done();
  });
}

describe('Simple', function() {
  describe('Test', function() {
      somePromise.then(function(data) {
        testFunc(data);
      });

      somePromise.then(function(data) {
        testFunc(data);
      });
  }
});
```

The promise is asynchronous, and maybe that's the reason why my "optimization" didn't work? I've found no "done" callback for `describe` function in docs.

Thanks in advance! Any help will be appreciate!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your example does not work [since Mocha has finished registering test cases when your promise resolves](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27851540/3636255).

## Testing the same promise with different assertions

To test a single promise using several assertions you simply need to create the promise at the start of the tests and then use it in the it blocks like the following:

```
describe('A module', function() {
    var promise;

    before(function () {
        promise = createPromise();
    });

    it('should do something', function() {
        return promise.then(function (value) {
            value.should.be.above(100);
        });
    });

    it('should do something else', function() {
        return promise.then(function (value) {
            value.should.be.below(200);
        });
    });
});
```

Note that if the promise is returned from an API call, the call will only be made once. [The result is simply cached in the promise for the two test cases.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise#Description)

This also makes use of the fact that [you can return promises from test cases](https://mochajs.org/#working-with-promises) instead of using a done callback. The test case will then fail if the promise is rejected or if any of the assertions in the then() calls fail.

## Testing different promises with the same assertions

Assuming that you want to test different promises using the same assertions you could pass a function to `testFunc` that creates the promise to be tested.

```
var testFunc = function(promiseFactory) {
  it('should do something', function(done) {
      promiseFactory().then(function(data) {
          data.should.above(100);
          done();
      });
  });
}

describe('Simple', function() {
  describe('Test', function() {
      testFunc(function () { return createSomePromise(); });

      testFunc(function () { return createSomeOtherPromise(); });
  });
});
```

This works since Mocha's `it` function is run immediately inside the describe block. The promises are then created using the `promiseFactory` callback when the test cases are actually run.

As you can also [return promises from test cases](https://mochajs.org/#working-with-promises) you can change `testFunc` to return an assertion as a promise like this:

```
var testFunc = function(promiseFactory) {
  it('should do something', function() {
      return promiseFactory().should.eventually.be.above(100);
  });
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it works. But could I test one promise using different assertions?

Comment: I was trying wrapping the `it` function inside my promise functions, so that I can request asynchronous api in my promise functions for only once but do different test

Comment: Yes of course. Promises makes this very easy. What you do is create the promise outside your test cases and assign it to a variable. You can then use the promise inside it blocks as usual. I have updated my answer with an example.

Comment: Thanks! I should dive deeper for Promise. Thank you again :)